# How can I pass only time parameter to a stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query which calculates the segments between start=6am and end=10pm. I want to keep the start and end variable to enable user to specify anything, so I created stored procedure with two time arguments variable but it is not working. Any idea why and how to fix it.

```
Create procedure spGetUptimeBetweenStartAndEnd
(start as time, end as time)
   Remaining query goes here
```

I tried

```
spGetUptimeBetweenStartAndEnd 6, 10
```

and

```
spGetUptimeBetweenStartAndEnd 6am, 10pm
```

but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a variable or parameter of `time` datatype, the Default string literal format passed to down-level client is : `hh:mm:ss[.nnnnnnn]`

So, assuming any of your code is not changing the default time string literal,  if the stored procedure `spGetUptimeBetweenStartAndEnd` uses parameters of the `time` datatype, then you must send values to it in the form :

```
spGetUptimeBetweenStartAndEnd '06:00:00.000000', '22:00:00.000000'
```